# switch ruby for a single command via rvm

Tags: ruby, bash, rvm

I want to use e.g. system capistrano/ruco/xxx and not add them to every ruby/gemset i create.

So usually do `rvm ruby_with_all_gems ... do_something ... rvm back_to_other`

Is there any nice solution that i could use to do e.g. `alias capree="rvm with ree cap"` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rvm exec ree cap` its already built i to rvm :>

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a function:

Pseudo code:

```
capree () {
    save rvm state
    do rvm op with args "$@"
    restore rvm state
}
```